# Does WordPress provide plugin override functionality the way Joomla does?

Tags: joomla, wordpress

I would like to override the output for a WordPress plugin in a similar manner as I would for Joomla, is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You can use filters to change data before it is output.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API#Filters

Or the `template_include` filter can be used to serve up a different custom template.
e.g.

```
function choose_template($template)
{
  if( $template == 'plugin-template-page.php' )
  {
    $template = 'my-template-page.php';
  }
  return $template;
}
add_filter('template_include','choose_template');
```